# Instagram fetch by tag

Tags: tags, instagram

I need fetch Instagram posts by tag every n minutes.. I use

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/MYTAG/media/recent?access_token=xx.xxxx

OK, but I don't want to get the same posts every time, I want just to fetch only the new posts.. I thought to use a param.. (for example `created_time`), save it, and to use it like a filter param in the next request, to save the created_time field of the last post.. save it, repeat this.

But API only allow these parameters:

> PARAMETERS
> COUNT   Count of tagged media to return.
> MIN_TAG_ID  Return media before this min_tag_id.
> MAX_TAG_ID  Return media after this max_tag_id.

Then I thought using `MIN_TAG_ID` in the request instead of `Created_time`, but the `TAG_ID` is not found in the API's response JSON ... (I can filter by `TAG_ID` but `TAG_ID` not come in the response. Unusual!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the response it is simply called `id` not `tag_id`

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use [subscriptions](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/). And you will process new posts in real-time.